# Is inertia still considered a mysterious force?

Tags: gravity, reference-frames, energy-conservation, inertia, machs-principle

When I first saw, for example, weightless objects in a space capsule, I assumed that pushing them would require no effort because, of course, they did not weigh anything. On Earth, heavy objects are not just hard to pick up but also to cause to move.

So as a youngster, I assumed that weightless objects also were easy to push. (I realize this is not rigorous, just what a 9 year old would think.) I never thought that they would be hard to push and when someone told me this, I then wondered, where does this resistance come from?

Later I read that some scientist suggested that it is the combined gravity of all the distant stars, etc. that causes this resistance so that actually, come to think of it, heavy objects are hard to push for the same reason they are hard to pick up.

However, even at 9 years old, my intuition would have been that in outer space a fast moving object would hurt if it hit me -- that is, it would be hard to stop.

So why do we have to invoke something mysterious such as the gravity of distant objects? Wouldn't the resistance of a massive object simply stem from the apparent contradiction that if it were very "easy" to set a massive object in motion but it was very "hard" to stop it once it was in motion, then you could (I think) generate energy by applying no force to massive objects and then use this "freely acquired" kinetic energy to turn a flywheel, etc.

So is this not a reasonable explanation of why an object resists motion without mentioning the gravitational influence of distant bodies?

Comment: you could look up mach's principle in wikipedia. this is not an obscure thing -- it is well known.

Answer (score 1):

In freefall objects have mass but no weight, so you still have to exert a force on an object to accelerate its mass. The more mass an object has, the greater the force required to produce the same acceleration, per Newton's second law of motion. This has nothing to do with gravity from distant objects, it is due to inertial resistance per Newton's first law of motion. You may want to read; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion

Comment: but mach's principle is, as i understand it, *why* there is inertial resistance and was of course suggested long after newton. maybe i don't understand what mach's principle is.

Comment: @releseabe The so-called "Mach's principle" is possibly the vaguest principle I've ever seen - you'll have to be a bit more specific

Comment: Mach's conjecture does not involve the gravity from distant stars, but uses them as a visual reference for angular momentum;   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach%27s_principle

Comment: this is what wikipedia says: There are a number of rival formulations of the principle. It is often stated in vague ways, like "mass out there influences inertia here".